# diagonalize multiple vectors using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Say I have a matrix of shape (2,3), I need to diagonalize the 3-elements vector into matrix of shape (3,3), for all the 2 vectors at once. That is, I need to return matrix with shape (2,3,3). How can I do that with Numpy elegantly ?

```
given data = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

i want the result [[[1,0,0],
                    [0,2,0],
                    [0,0,3]],
                    
                   [[4,0,0],
                    [0,5,0],
                    [0,0,6]]]
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a (maybe smaller, 3x2) example for clarity?

Comment: What would the output be for this input?

Comment: I think he wants the output to be a 2x3x3 array in which result[0] is a matrix with diagonal 1, 2, 3 and result[1] is a matrix with diagonal 4, 5, 6.

Comment: `np.einsum('ij,kj->kij', np.eye(data.shape[1], dtype=data.dtype), data)`, IIUC.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny.  Yeah.  But that's using a matrix multiply to perform what should be a copy operation.  Probably O(n^2) in the number of elements rather than O(n).  But for this small case, doesn't much matter.

Comment: Thank you all for your great ideas, helpful !

Comment: Now you should pick which one you like best and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr, my one-liner: `mydiag=np.vectorize(np.diag, signature='(n)->(n,n)')`

I suppose here that by "diagonalize" you mean "applying np.diag".
Which, as a teacher of linear algebra, tickles me a bit. Since "diagonalizing" has a specific meaning, which is not that (it is computing eigen vectors and values, and from there, writing M=P⁻¹ΛP. Which you cannot do from the inputs you have).

So, I suppose that if input matrix is

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [9, 8, 7]]
```

The output matrix you want is

```
[[[1, 0, 0],
  [0, 2, 0],
  [0, 0, 3]],
 [[9, 0, 0],
  [0, 8, 0],
  [0, 0, 7]]]
```

If not, you can ignore this answer [Edit: in the meantime, you explained exactly that. So yo may continue to read].

There are many way to do that.
My one liner would be

```py
mydiag=np.vectorize(np.diag, signature='(n)->(n,n)')
```

Which build a new functions which does what you want (it interprets the input as a list of 1D-array, call np.diag of each of them, to get a 2D-array, and put each 2D-array in a numpy array, thus getting a 3D-array)

Then, you just call `mydiag(M)`

One advantage of vectorize, is that it uses numpy broadcasting. In other words, the loops are executed in C, not in python. In yet other words, it is faster. Well it is supposed to be (on small matrix, it is in fact slower than Michael's method - in comment; on large matrix, it is has the exact same speed. Which is frustrating, since einsum doc itself specify that it sacrifices broadcasting).

Plus, it is a one-liner, which has no other interest than bragging on forums. But well, here we are.

Comment: It's actually quite slow compared to my approach (24 vs 4ms for mine on a 100x100 input, it doesn't even run on a 1000x1000 input vs 2s for mine) ;)

Comment: I get different results for (100,100) 9.27 ms (chrslg), 4.92 ms (mozway), 8.73 ms (einsum), 8.11 ms (broadcast), **4.73 ms** (FrankYellin). I'm quite impressed how fast this solution is (excluding the time to `vectorize` because the function will probably be used more than once).

Comment: Those are also the timings (with a factor 2) I get. Index based methods are obviously faster in such a case, where it is a matter of copying data in the right place, without computation.

Comment: Note that this is machine dependent. On a big mac, with semi-vectorization, I get 1,42 ms for all 4 methods. With many combination of sizes, it always come to similar timings on my Mac, but twice faster timings on my PC for "index" methods.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way with indexing:

```
out = np.zeros(data.shape+(data.shape[-1],), dtype=data.dtype)

x,y = np.indices(data.shape).reshape(2, -1)
out[x,y,y] = data.ravel()
```

output:

```
array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 2, 0],
        [0, 0, 3]],

       [[4, 0, 0],
        [0, 5, 0],
        [0, 0, 6]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

We use array indexing to precisely grab those elements that are on the diagonal. Note that array indexing allows broadcasting between the indices, so we have index1 contain the index of the array, and index2 contain the index of the diagonal element.

```
index1 = np.arange(2)[:, None] # 2 is the number of arrays
index2 = np.arange(3)[None, :] # 3 is the square size of each matrix

result = np.zeros((2, 3, 3))
result[index1, index2, index2] = data
```